# Serve 404 from HAProxy when no acls match

Tags: haproxy, http-status-code-404

I'm currently re-configuring HAProxy using 1.5dev-17. What I'd like to do is return a 404 error when there is no backend to use for a particular request.

Our current configuration uses the default_backend to route to our django app servers, but when there are a whole lot of probing requests (like a pen-test) that match none of the other configured backends, our django servers grind to a halt as they try to serve these invalid requests, eventually returning a 404.

I'd like to serve the 404 from HAProxy rather than delegating to the django backends. I'm currently achieving this with a hack:

```
frontend www
    ...
    default_backend nomatch

backend nomatch
    errorfile 503 /var/www/http/404.http
```

And within the 404.http file I set the 404 status code in the headers. This works, but feels very wrong. Is there a better way of achieving this with HAProxy? Or should I use a regular backend and just let that handle responding with a 404?

Comment: What's the contents of the 404.http file?

Comment: @JasonFloyd `HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found` followed by some other headers, then a blank line, then the `<html>` content.

Answer (score 16):

If you would be okay with any of the following response codes: 200, 400, 403, 405, 408, 429, 500, 502, 503, or 504.

Then you could do something like this:

```
frontend www
  ...
  default_backend no-match

backend no-match
  mode http
  http-request deny deny_status 400
```

- `http-request`: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4-http-request
- Accepted response codes described in `errorfile`: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#errorfile

edit: newer versions off HAProxy also support 404 as return code: https://docs.haproxy.org/2.4/configuration.html#3.8-errorfile

Answer (score 2):

After wanting something similar this is the same thing I came up with. It felt wrong but it works very well in practice and is much cleaner than trying to blacklist particular urls. Just be sure to leave a comment so no one comes across it thinking it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what the OP asked for, but in case you the reader stumbled across here while using TCP mode (like I did), the corresponding directive you want to use is [`tcp-request content`](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#tcp-request%20content). So you would have:

```
frontend my-tcp
  ...
  default_backend no-match

backend no-match
  tcp-request content reject
```

Of course in TCP mode there's no HTTP response code. You can also use `silent-drop` instead of `reject` if you so wish.

---

Note that you **CANNOT** use `tcp-request connection` because [it cannot be used in a `backend` section](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#tcp-request%20connection). If you try to put it in a `frontend` section instead, `haproxy` will warn you:

> a 'tcp-request' rule placed after a 'use_backend' rule will still be processed before

... which means it's overriding all your `use_backend` and `default_backend` directives.

While you technically *CAN* use `tcp-response content`, there's no good reason to do so in this use case (as compared to using `tcp-request content`.